# Add ActionListener to JMenuItem Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, actionlistener, jmenuitem

I have a GUI going in Netbeans.. The only problem that I have is to add events to my `JMenuItems`. I'm currently loading a `String[]` in as my `menulist` adding a new `JMenuItem` for `.length`

```
private void addToGamePanel(){
      String[] gameNames =  con.getGameNames();
      for (int i = 0; i < gameNames.length; i++) {
        jMenu2.add(new JMenuItem(gameNames[i]));

      }        
}
```

My problem is then how to add action events for the `JMenuItem`.. I cant set the event in the GUI window cause the Item is not made before the load of `gameNames`.

Comment: What event listeners do you want to register?

Comment: Not sure I get you... but I just wonder how to add events/actionPerformed to the JMenuItems.. A friend said something about a listener but I'm really not sure how..

Comment: You are adding a menu item for each item in the String[] gameNames. Do you also have an array of event listeners? Or should they all use the same listener?

Comment: I'm guessing one listener should be enough.. it should just return the name of the item clikced on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass each of your menu items an action listener. One possibility is to have your class implement the `ActionListener` interface and define the method `actionPerformed`.

```
class YourClass implements ActionListener {

    [...]

    private void addToGamePanel(){

        String[] gameNames =  con.getGameNames();
        for (int i = 0; i < gameNames.length; i++) {

            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(gameNames[i])
            item.addActionListener(this);
            jMenu2.add(item);
         }        
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JMenuItem menuItem = (JMenuItem)(e.getSource());

        // do something with your menu item
        String text = menuItem.getText();

    }
}
```

In this case, your instance of the class also acts as the ActionListener. For simple things, you can also use an anonymous class

```
    private void addToGamePanel(){

        String[] gameNames =  con.getGameNames();
        for (int i = 0; i < gameNames.length; i++) {
            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(gameNames[i])
            item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JMenuItem menuItem = (JMenuItem) e.getSource();
                    // do something with your menu item
                    String text = menuItem.getText();
                }
            });
            jMenu2.add(item);
         }
    }
```

If you have some more advanced needs, you might consider defining a separate ActionListener or even better an Action, have a look at: [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Comment: the problem is just that its inside a GUI main... And that allready implements java.swing

Comment: Consider adding relevant information like this to the question beforehand. What problem, is there an error message? You mean a main method?

Comment: Just gonna try the second thing

Comment: Please vote for the answer if it was helpful and consider accepting it, if it solved your problem. See: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: You are actually creating an anonymous instance of ActionListener, and if you implement the method actionPerformed, it's fine.